# How to include System.IO Reference file?

Tags: asp.net

I'm building an ASP.Net application that requires the System.IO namespace. (Using iTextSharp to create a PDF).

Do I only need to type:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
```

or do I need to also add the System.IO reference in my Solution Explorer? I ask because I can't find this "System.IO". I only see "System.IO.Log" when I try to add a reference.

See System.IO is missing:
[image: References available to add]

Comment: Yes you do need to add the System.IO reference. If it is not there, make sure you have the .NET Framework loaded for the version you are programming.

Comment: Note that your using statements listed in the question have nothing to do with having System.IO available for iTextSharp (they are irrelevant to the question). Using statements don't load anything, they only provide a semantic shortcut when referencing classes in that file.

Comment: I started my project with the .Net Framework 4.0. I'll add a screenshot above if I can. Should System.IO be in that list? If it's missing for some reason is there a way to get just that missing one back again?

Answer (score 2):

The reference and the using statement are two different things albeit related. Regardless you'll need to reference System.IO through Solution Explorer.

With that said, you'll only need to include the using statement if you'd like a shortcut to "using" the functionality of System.IO in the class. If iTextSharp is the only thing that is consuming System.IO there's no need for the using statement.